# Activating godmode in Super Star Wars for SNES?

Tags: snes, super-star-wars

I tried entering `A A A A X B B B B Y X X X X A Y Y Y Y B` like it says, but nothing happens. The below video shows it going to a character select screen afterwards when you start the game, but this doesn't happen to me. I have the controller in port 1 with no controller in port 2. Am I missing something about this?

Answer (score 2):

Per this [Gamefaqs Cheat](https://www.gamefaqs.com/snes/563218-super-star-wars/cheats) guide, you are not entering in the code during the game play which is required to be done by the 2nd controller.

*(Emphasis my own)*

> Press A, A, A, A, X, B, B, B, B, Y, X, X, X, X, A, Y, Y, Y, Y, B at the title screen. **During game, press A+B+X+Y+Select on controller 2**